# How to change the owner of the directory created by shell_exec , by default the owner of 'group' and 'user, is daemon?

Tags: php, daemon, shell-exec

when I try to run this command from a PHP file:

```
shell_exec(("mkdir test"));
```

If I check the owner of this 'test' directory then it shows the 'user' and 'group' owner as 'daemon' (I don't want this to be daemon). How to change the owner of this directory dynamically. If I am adding this line to my code, even then nothing is changing.

```
shell_exec("echo password | sudo -S chown -R group:user test");
```

But when I run above command from the terminal:

```
 echo password | sudo -S chown -R group:user test
```

then I am able to change the owner. I want to change the owner (which is currently set as daemon) of the dynamically created directory by a script not by writing command in terminal. 
Any information will be really appreciated.

Comment: you would need to change the permissions the php user has (usually a bad idea)

Comment: @nogad I am already running above commands after changing the permissions of the PHP user, but it is not solving my problem, process is still creating the directory as daemon user.

Comment: You cannot "gift" a file or directory unless you are the root user. And you definitely doesn't want to run your script with root levels. Why do you want to change the owner of the directory? Can't you just handle the rights with a group the web server user and the actual user are in?

Comment: @Progman Actually I am trying to create a 'django' project with a script, for this I am using the command 'django-admin startproject test'  this command will give me a directory named 'test' which will have some django files, the only problem I am facing is when I run above command with 'shell_exec' it give me a  directory named 'test' whose user and group is daemon, Now if I am running a other django command from script like 'shell_exec('python test/manage.py inspectdb') after creating 'test' then it is not working because the user and group for the 'test' is daemon.

Comment: So I guess I have two options to make it work: 1) The process which is creating the 'test' should run as user not as a daemon , I am still searching for this solution.  2) The second idea that came in my mind is after creating the 'test' change its ownership by 'shell_exec(' echo password | sudo -S chown -R group:user test')' but shell_exec is not able to change the owner , but this command is not able to change the owner from shell_exec.